# RTC Where is the output properties file config in build definition 'Command Line' Tab and how to use 'Evvironment Variables'

Tags: replace, properties, config, rtc

I'm using RTC(Rational Team Concert) to build project. Coz there's a property file in my project which include code like this -

```
url=@COMMON_URL@
dir=@REPORT_DIR@
```

I need to replace these properties as real variable according to different envirenment when build, it seems I can do that by config 'Properties file' and 'Environment variables' in build definition 'Command Line' Tab. But I've tried several times, I cannot find the output file(Properties file contain all build definition) and don't know how to replace my file in project.

If someone is familiar with RTC, plase help me, thanks.

Comment: I've got that location of output file is "/BuildDir/RTCWORK/buildEngineName", but I still don't know how to replace file in my project.

Answer (score 0):

In Build definition there u can find the properties tab..there you can add your environment variables->save that build definition ->go to Build Fore tab->click on Synchronize Properties button (it will load your new env variable to server)->it will again modifies the build definition, but dont save it.

Answer (score 0):

Those environment variables (defined in the properties tab of a build definition or a build request) should be passed along to the Build Engine associated with the Build Definition, and be present on the actual Build master itself (BuildForge, Hudson, Jenkins, ...) when said build will start.

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/3.0/bf-rtc-integration/images/4_build_definition_properties.png]

That means your actual build script has the opportunity to modify your config file, replacing the placeholder `@COMMON_URL@` with the value derived from the environment variable `$COMMON_URL`.